# Retrieving data from database using spring integration JDBC without poll

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-integration, integration

Currently learning spring integration, I want to retrieve information from a MySQL database to use inside an `int:service-activator`, or an `int:splitter` .

Unfortunately, it would seem that most examples and documentation is based around the idea of using an `int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter`, which in itself requires a poller. I don't want to poll a database, but rather retrieve specific data based on the payload of an existing message originating from an `int:gateway`. This data would then be used to further modify the payload, or assist in how the message is split.

I tried using `int-jdbc:outbound-gateway`, as the description states:

> ... jdbc.JdbcOutboundGateway' for updating a database in response to a message on the request channel, and/or for retrieving data from the database ...

This implies that it can be used for retrieval of data only and not just updates, but as I implement it, there's a complaint that at least one update statement is required:

[image: Update required for outbound-gateway]

And so I'm currently sitting with a faulty prototype that initially looks like so:

[image: Start of integration-context diagram]

The circled piece being the non-functioning `int-jdbc:outbound-gateway`.

My end goal is to, based on the payload coming from the `incomingGateway` (in the picture above), retrieve some information from a MySQL database, and use that data to split the message in the `analyzerSplitter`, or to perhaps modify the payload using an `int:service-activator`. This should then all be linked up to a `int-jdbc:message-store` which I believe could assist with performance. I do not wish to poll the database on a regular basis, and I do not wish to update anything in the database.

By testing using the polling `int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter`, I am confident that my datasource bean is set up correctly and the query can execute.

How would I go about correctly setting up such behaviour in spring integration?

Comment: Not knowing this at all, I'd expect something called **inbound** not outbound to select data.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel outbound gateway (in this context) means request/reply to some external system (a database in this case). An outbound channel adapter can be used to "just" update a DB at the end of a flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed with the flow after updating the database, you can simply use a `JdbcTemplate` in a method invoked by a service activator, or, if it's the end of the flow, use an [outbound channel adapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-channel-adapter).

> The outbound channel adapter is the inverse of the inbound: its role is to handle a message and use it to execute a SQL query. By default, the message payload and headers are available as input parameters to the query, as the following example shows:
>
> ...